# Is It possible to use Google One VPN with another VPN?

Tags: networking, vpn, internet, ip, routing

I would like to use Google One VPN in a country where it isn't supported by connecting from my IP to a VPN and from that to Google One VPN on Windows.

For example I've tried using VPNs like Proton and then connecting to Google One, but that doesn't work as Google one says no Internet, presumably because it conflicts with the other VPN, is there any way to make the other VPN seem like my real IP address to Google VPN?

Comment: If your router can do VPN, then you can do the second VPN from the computer.

Comment: Google VPN may recognize the other VPN provider and deny connecting to it. Its a bit of a hit and miss if it will work.